# How to hide ng-template in p-datatable in angular so it does not take up space if no value is present in row?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, angular-ng-if

The required output is that it does not take up space if rowsToExpand does not contain description i.e. ng-template should be hidden. How can we add a check on ng-template to avoid above issue.

```
<p-dataTable [expandedRows]="rowsToExpand" expandableRows="true" 
[value]="rowsToExpand" tableStyleClass="table table-striped table-bordered    
table-inherit">
    <p-column field="item" header="Serialno"></p-column>
    ......
    <ng-template let-rowInfo pTemplate="rowexpansion">
        <span *ngIf="rowInfo.Description">
        ......
        </span>
    </ng-template>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
<ng-template let-rowInfo pTemplate="rowexpansion">
      <span *ngIf="rowInfo.Description">
            ......
      </span>
</ng-template>
```

change to

```
<ng-template *ngIf="rowInfo.Description" let-rowInfo pTemplate="rowexpansion">
       <span >
           ......
       </span>
 </ng-template>
```

> Otherwise call the template if description exists

```
<p-dataTable [expandedRows]="rowsToExpand" expandableRows="true" 
 [value]="rowsToExpand" tableStyleClass="table table-striped table-bordered    
    table-inherit">
    <p-column field="item" header="Serialno"></p-column>
    ......

    <div *ngIf="rowInfo.Description then description">

</p-dataTable>

<ng-template #description let-rowInfo pTemplate="rowexpansion">
      <span *ngIf="rowInfo.Description">
            ......
      </span>
</ng-template>
```